# Insert Query Bug

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I'm trying to insert a string into the database , but when it contains single quote('), the query becomes invalid.

```
$set_content=$_POST['content']; 

$result = pg_query($db,"INSERT INTO programmes(title,picture,content) VALUES('$set_title','$pic_path','$set_content');");
```

Comment: Instead of making yourself vulnerable to SQL Injection, use prepared statements and you won't have this problem: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php

Comment: you can't use PHP variable inside single quote.

try with below query

    $set_content=$_POST['content']; 
    
    $result = pg_query($db,"INSERT INTO programmes(title,picture,content) VALUES('".$set_title."','".$pic_path."','".$set_content."');");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php

> Warning
>
> String interpolation of user-supplied data is extremely dangerous and
>   is likely to lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. In most cases
>   pg_query_params() should be preferred, passing user-supplied values as
>   parameters rather than substituting them into the query string.

```
$result = pg_query_params($db,"INSERT INTO programmes(title,picture,content) VALUES($1,$2,$3);",Array($set_title,$pic_path,$set_content));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked out. the query is passing perfectly now.

Comment: We shouldn't be answering such blatant duplicates.